# A Jewish-slaves Mitzvahs obligations

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, employment, slave-serve-eved-avadim

What mitzvos is a Jewish slave (a Jew owned by a Jew mentioned Shemot [21,2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) obligated in?

Is a Jewish slave obligated in time bound mitzvos?
or he obligated to the same mitzvos as a woman?

Sources please

Comment: Positive? Negative? Please clarify this sitch

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I want all info on this subject (thank you)

Comment: Unless you already know the answer, why would you think that a male slave is obligated like a woman?

Comment: @Doniel because Eved Kenani is generally only obligated like a woman

Comment: @Double Like I said, unless you already know the answer this question makes no sense.

Comment: @DonielF I don't know the answer [for sure but I strongly assume it's that he's obligated in everything]

Comment: @DoubleAA Except for being permitted a shifcha kenaanit if his master so demands

Comment: @DoubleAA forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=22908#p228263 they say the Ramban says he is like a womab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *eved Ivri* is still Chayav in all Mitzvos, as it says in [Teshuvos Radvaz 4,1259](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_4.1259.2?vhe=Teshuvot_HaRadbaz,_Warsaw_1882&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> הרי עבד עברי חייב בכל מצות שבתורה

The Radvaz continues that there is a Dispute between the Rambam and Onklos whether *min Hatorah* a *yisroel* can marry a *shifcha canaanis

- *shifcha Canaanis* which is prohibited from thee Torah "Lo Yihye Kadesh" (devarim 23,18)which is explained by Onkles one should not marry a slavewoman  (Rashi Kidushin 69a)
- He was allowed *mideorasa* to marry her and only prohibited *miderabanan* and the rabbis lifted their decree with an *Eved Ivri* as the Torah says the master can force him to marry a Shifcha (Maharashdam Yore dea 196 interpretation of Rambam Avadim perek 3)

According to the Rambam there is absolutely no difference Mideoraisa between a regular *yisroel* and an *eved Ivri*, whereas rashi and onklos hold an *eved ivri* exempt from one Mitzva of marrying a *shifcha Canaanis* which is prohibited to a Yisroel *mideoraisa*.